# "Former England footballer husband David" - adjective association

Tags: adjectives

In an article about the increased unprofitability of Victoria Beckham's fashion business the following appears :

> The company is controlled by Mrs Beckham and her former England footballer husband David.

[ITV - 27th November 2019](https://www.itv.com/news/2019-11-27/losses-deepen-at-victoria-beckhams-fashion-business-after-demand-wanes/)

At first reading, I assumed that I had simply not noticed a celebrity divorce in my  day to day news-reading. Then I wondered if he now played for Scotland. And I finished with a query about what sport David now participates in.

Or . . . .  could he now be called John ?

Is there a term for this ambiguous attachment of an adjective that could well be associated with any of the four nouns that follow ?

Comment: I don't know a term for it.

Comment: Were the article about a non famous couple, would  it still be ambiguous?

Comment: @user067531 My own brain immediately assumes the adjective should attach to the last noun possible (not the proper noun, obviously), therefore I at first assumed a divorce.

Comment: So it is just an unclear sentence, why should there be a specific term for it?

Comment: I say we coin something for it.

Comment: @user067531 There's a term for everything else in grammar. I assumed this would have been labelled.

Comment: The string consists of **_stacked modifiers_**, About which the [Wayfield Handbook of Technical and Scientific Writing](http://www.mit.edu/course/21/21.guide/stacked.htm) has this to say: 'Stacked Modifiers and Nouns ... Avoid using long strings of modifiers or nouns. These stacked modifiers and nouns can be hard to read and sometimes create ambiguity. Add a few words (especially prepositions and conjunctions) to make the relationships between nouns clear to the reader.' And which have been covered before. But I'd avoid _excessive stacked modifier ambiguity_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes - better would be "her husband David, the former England footballer".  David probably still plays football, if only with kids in the park. And as far as I know he is still an Englishman. So neither "England", nor "footballer" can, by themselves be regarded as "former".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What is the difference between 'sequential' and 'stacked' ?

Comment: @Nigel J I'm using 'sequential' to mean in a given order, but all modifying the head noun. Cumulative or coordinate. _A nice little old lady?. /  _Dull, incessant throbbing._  'Stacked' to mean again in a given order, but now where one modifier may be modifying another as in the example given ([England footballer], for instance).

Comment: Thank you @EdwinAshworth

Comment: I think "<country> footballer" is a pretty common construct in journalism used to describe those sports-people. Those who don't read/see a lot of that sort of media are more likely to be confused by the ambiguity.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "Stacked order ambiguity" does sound like a pretty legit (if unofficial) way to describe it. That's worth putting down as an answer, I'd say.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  My apologies, I meant "stacked modifier ambiguity", as you had stated originally in your comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/519308/former-england-footballer-husband-david-adjective-association?noredirect=1#comment1261885_519308

Comment: @John Go-Soco But it's not even a moderately strong collocation, and far from being a fixed 'term'. ELU is about established usage, not pontification; I'd downvote 'stacked order ambiguity' given as an answer (like 'former-England-footballer-husbandism' or  'there doesn't seem to be a term ...').

Comment: This is why you need to hyphenate: *The company is controlled by Mrs. Beckham and her former-England-footballer husband, David.* Or rephrase: *The company is controlled by Mrs Beckham and her husband, David, the former England footballer.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NP

> *her former England footballer husband David*

comprises a smaller NP *her former England footballer husband* and two nominals *former England footballer husband* and *David*:

> [<sub>NP</sub> [<sub>NP</sub> *her* [<sub>Nominal</sub> *former England footballer husband*]] [<sub>Nominal</sub> *David*]]

According to The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (Page 447) by Huddleston and Pullum, *David* is an appositive modifier that post-modifies the smaller NP.

The first nominal can be called a complex nominal, which a paper titled "[Rethinking the Semantics of Complex Nominals](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-72665-4_43)" defines as follows:

> a sequence of one or more nouns or adjectives preceding a head noun. Instances of such a construction include *apple pie*, *information retrieval system*, *computer book sale*, *former political activist*, etc.

As [this Language Log post](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=32860) shows, the ambiguity of a complex nominal does not necessarily arise from having an adjective but from having a combination of multiple words including a head noun with or without one or more adjectives.

So the term you're looking for may be 'complex nominal' itself.

For the intended interpretation of the complex nominal in the ITV article, the complex nominal should be figured out as follows:

> [[*former* [*England footballer*]] *husband*]

Where *England footballer* and  *former England footballer* are also complex nominals.